# What is the purpose of defining a function as an IIFE returning a function?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In three.js source, there are multiple usage of this pattern. It seems that taking out the IIFE will not make any difference. My guess is that a named function is perfered over an anonymous function.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js

```
Object.assign( THREE.Object3D.prototype, ..., {

    ...

    rotateX : function () {

        var v1 = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );

        return function rotateX( angle ) {
            return this.rotateOnAxis( v1, angle );
        };
    }(),

    ...

})
```

Comment: What would happen to `v1` if you took out the IIFE? It *does* make a difference.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/

Comment: possibly related: [the three.js sources might be a mess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21533862/1048572)

Comment: The reason for the IIFE pattern is for performance. Note that `rotateX` in your example does not need to instantiate a new `v1` vector every time `rotateX` is called, but rather puts it in a closure to be used repeatedly. If rotateX is called many times, it does not waste time and memory instantiating and then garbage collecting a variable which is essentially acting as a constant. It also provides privacy due to the closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a closure, giving the function access to the value of `v1` without putting the `v1` variable in a scope any wider than necessary.